# Git workflow to commit to either of two previous revisions

Tags: git, git-svn

I've got a workflow at the moment where I'm working on a bug and any changes I make are of two types:

- Improving the logging and assertions to try to investigate the bug, but without affecting the logic ([Heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug) notwithstanding)
- Logic changes that try to fix the bug

Initially I add some logging and commit it as revision A. I then make some logic changes that go towards fixing the bug and commit as revision B.  I now understand a bit more about the bug and so I can add some more logging.

My question is, how can I add those extra checks back to revision A?  Ultimately I want to end up with two commits -- the first one is just the extra diagnostics and the fix is in the second.  I guess the functionality is a bit like 'amend previous commit', but I want it to apply to an older commit, not the latest one.

I can see that I could probably do this by creating a branch from revision A and committing the new change there, then apply revision B and so some kind of squashing. Is there a simpler way?

I'm using `git-svn`, but I imagine the solution would be a git one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have not committed your changes to the subversion repository yet, you can do an interactive rebase.

```
git rebase -i <commit before your changes>
# define order you want commits to appear
# optionally merge commits by replacing 'pick' with 'squash'/'s' or 'fixup'/'f'
# save and exit editor
# make sure resulting history is correct
```

This changes history, so you should never do it on published history. And *NEVER EVER* with history already written to the subversion repository (your next dcommit will go terribly wrong!). Also be careful to not lose any changes or commits.